# how does sqlx::query_as and sqlx::query_as! differ?

Tags: rust

How does `sqlx::query` & `sqlx::query!` as differ ?
as well as how does `sqlx::query_as` and `sqlx::query_as!` differ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.rs/sqlx/0.3.4/sqlx/macro.query.html

> Statically checked SQL query with `println!()` style syntax.

What this means is that `sqlx` will check that your SQL string is formatted correctly at compile time, letting you know about a mistake sooner, and allowing the runtime code to omit these checks